# how to add cookies so that a loader will only show up once a day

Tags: reactjs

```
class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }, 1500)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.loading ?
        <LoadingScreen></LoadingScreen>
        :
        <OptionScreen></OptionScreen>
    )
  }
}
```

I want the loading screen to only show up only once a day (refreshes after a day).
teammate told me to use cookies but I'm not sure

help please?????

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is not feasible.

You can call "setInterval" or "setTimeout" to refresh the current page: window.location.reload(false);